# How to control the for loop with a if condition in it not to give output till the loop completes

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a method which is having a Map with a set of rules which I am trying to apply on input with an `if` condition.

When the condition is matched then the if will break the loop and return the matched value. If none of the conditions is matched, I need to return a `null` output that the input didn't satisfy any given condition.

My current code as below

```
public static String matching(String input){

    HashMap<String, String> hm =  new HashMap<String, String>();

    //Key,Value pair in Hashmap represents Name of condition(Key) and Condition(value)    
    for (Map.Entry mapElement : hm.entrySet()) { 
        String value = mapElement.getValue();
        if(input.equals(condition)){
            return input;
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Let's say the map has 5 entries and the condition which will satisfy the current input is present at the 5th position. The first four tests return `null` and when the condition at 5th position is matched it will return that matched condition. But I want to return the output only after evaluating all conditions in the map.
I tried putting `else if` after the `if` in the loop with a `continue;`, but it's giving the same result.

Please, how can I solve the issue ?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You can not return from your function and then go back to execute it once more.

Comment: Just a comment: it won't solve your problem, but that `break` after the `return` statement is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Just put a temporary variable in your for loop, assign it to null. If your if statement satisfied, assign the satisfied value to your temporary variable. After all the iterations complete it will return last satisfied value, otherwise it will return null. Then you can say that all entries iterated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `return` the loop will break and get out of the function.
If you want the evaluation of the whole map you can retun an array of results;

```
public static String matching(String input){

    ArrayList<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> hm =  new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Map.Entry mapElement : hm.entrySet()) { 
        String value = mapElement.getValue();
        if(input.equals(condition)){
            results.add(input);
        }
        else {
          results.add(null);
        }
    }

    // return all the result in 1 ArrayList. If your element in position 4 is your match the output will be:
    // [null, null, null, null, <input>]
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a return in the if then the for loop Will break and return the value.
Instead the if is not satisfied the for loop will terminate and return the null value outside the loop.

in a method the return break the function

Comment: sorry @Francesco Attorre  i didn't get what your saying

Comment: When you have a  return the method will not continue in any case, so you havde to call a return only when you finished every check, like @GameDroids answer

Answer (score 1):

For these cases you can use a "run" variable. Declare the output variable before entering the `for` loop (set it to `null`) and then set the result based on your conditions. This way you can make sure you loop over every input and if no condition is met, your variable is still `null`:

```
public static String matching(String input){

  String result = null;  // we declare the result here and return it in the end

    HashMap<String, String> hm =  new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Map.Entry mapElement : hm.entrySet()) { 
        String value = mapElement.getValue();
        if(input.equals(condition)){
            result = input;           // the input is the result if it meats the condition
            break;                    // the return at this point would make the break obsolete
        }
    }
    return result;                    // if (and only if) the condition is met your result variable has a value - otherwise it will be null
}
```

**EDIT** here is a more type-safe solution:

```
public static String matching(String input){

    String result = null;  // we declare the result here and return it in the end

    HashMap<String, String> hm =  new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (String key : hm.keySet()) {  // personally I find it easier to read and to follow 
        String value = hm.get(key);   // here the value will still be a String
        if(input.equals(condition)){  // FYI for more precise conditions you can also use input.equalsIgnoreCase(condition)
            result = input;           // the input is the result if it meets the condition
            break;                    // the return at this point would make the break obsolete
        }
    }
    return result;                    // if (and only if) the condition is met your result variable has a value - otherwise it will be null
}
```

Comment: remark: unlike @John Doe's answer, here it will only return a single result (the last condition meat)

Answer (score 1):

You can return only once from your method, if you need to store the value of unsuccessful matches then you better use a data store like List or Array.
Try something like this.

```
public static String matching(String input){

    HashMap<String, String> hm =  new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>(hm.size()); //same size as the map.

    //Key,Value pair in Hashmap represents Name of condition(Key) and Condition(value)    
    for (Map.Entry mapElement : hm.entrySet()) { 
        String value = mapElement.getValue();
        if(input.equals(condition)){
            strList.add(input);
            break;
        }else{
            strList.add(null);
        }
    }
    return strList;
}
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to return the condition (in case it is not a simple `String.equals`). @YRK, with this you can be sure to see all conditions that where meat (and the number of conditions). But if your values are all strings and your input is a string as well - and if you really only test `input.equals(condition)` then all you need to return is `true` or `false`... because you already know your input (before calling the method) and you when you return `true` you know that the input meats a condition (with the exact same value - the two strings are equal)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you are using ***HashMap*** - you cant be sure about the order.

Secondly - it depends, if you want to record all conditions that fits the input then just make separate collection and add them there within your loop. If the collection is empty - you simply return null.

Look at this sample code:

```
   final String input = "testValue2";
   Map<String, String> conditions = new HashMap<>();
   conditions.put("testKey1", "testValue1");
   conditions.put("testKey2", "testValue2");

   Set<Map.Entry> entrySetThatMatches = conditions.entrySet().stream().filter(m -> input.equals(m.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
   System.out.println(entrySetThatMatches.iterator().next().getValue()); //prints testValue2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the body with this code:

```
    for (String value : hm.values()) {
        if (input.equals(value)) {
            return input;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

- you can't have code after return statement
- .entrySet() returns Map.Entry and if you are not using <> operator getValue() returns Object instead of String